# Informal way of saying some time expressions

Tags: phrases, formality, informal-language, conversation

I was wondering what the informal equivalent for the following expressions are:

**A matter of time**

> It is **a matter of time**, before somebody find it

**As time goes by**

> As time goes by, he found that his colleague is dishonest.

In other words, How can I use these phrases in my conversation?

Answer (score -2):

Do you want equivalent expressions or do you want to know how to use the given phrases? These seem like contradictory requests. Nevertheless...

*A matter of time* is not particularly formal. It's used in everyday conversation. But you should use *It's* in conversational English, remove the comma, and use the correct verb conjugation:

> It's a matter of time before somebody finds it.

Note that *somebody* is correctly used rather than the somewhat more formal *someone*.

Again, *as time goes by* is not necessarily formal. But *over time* is probably less formal than it.

One problem is that you cannot use a past tense with *as time goes by*. So

> *As time goes by, he found that his colleague is dishonest.

is ungrammatical, which is what the asterisk (*) before it means.

You can say *as time went by* with a past tense verb,  but that is somewhat formal.

I suggest

> Over time he found that his colleague  was dishonest.

Hope this helps!